# jQuery Draggable with containment parent won't scroll

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a div that is position: absolute and it contains items that get dragged. I want to set the containment of their drag to parent but when I do scrolling doesn't seem to work.

Here's a jsfiddle example http://jsfiddle.net/pJXVH/1/

Can anyone tell me if there is a way to get around this? While maintaining a layout that has a 'fill remainder' div?

Comment: What browser did you try this on? In Chrome v19.0.1084.56 this seems to work fine when you bind the containment area to the parent div.

Comment: Yes this was only tested on Chrome 19.0.1084.56, it wont scroll for me when it is set to 'parent'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So here's my current solution to the issue, I changed the way that the containment is set. I do not use parent. I just set the left and top, but I use

```
containment :[10, $('.desktop').offset().top]
```

and then inside of my function that hides the banner:

```
$('.ui-draggable').draggable('option', 'containment',  [10, $('.desktop').offset().top]);
```

This changes the containment as needed...

I would prefer an answer that is more css or $.draggable oriented but this will serve my purposes.

If you find a better way please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

use that

$('.item').draggable({containment: $('.selector').parent()
, scroll:true});

see this
http://jsfiddle.net/bilalahmed07/pJXVH/5/

Comment: Did you intend to leave that as $('.selector').parent()? because on Chrome 19.0.1084.56, you can drag the items anywhere... it scrolls yes, but it should NOT allow you to drag an item outside the blue area. When I change .selector to .item, it still wont let me scroll.